# Downloading a file with Selenium-hub in docker where the content-type header changes on load (Java)

Tags: java, docker, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Okay, so I'm currently automating an old, quite strangely put together ASP application via Selenium coupled with ChromeDriver. Everything works completely fine when run locally with a Chrome browser and the latest ChromeDriver executable, however when switching to running the application in Docker with selenium-hub, I experience this issue.

The file in question is generated on the fly by the ASP application based upon data currently selected by the user. The users latest query is seemingly cached against their session ID somewhere, and when you click the export button it fires off a JavaScript event which executes a window.open command to load a page. This page looks up the last query from the current user (stored in a cookie) and creates a file to download. Once the file is ready, it changes the content-type header of file to a different MIME type and sets a file name, and then the browser downloads it. The format of the file is even worse, as they download it as an XLS document, however it's actually a HTML document inside that can easily be rendered by a browser.

This is all fine (well, as fine as it can be!) when it's running in a normal instance of Chrome, however when using the docker based (or indeed a local headless) instance the download never actually occurs. I've tried the following:

- Setting the downloads directory manually
- Disable popup blocking
- Setting the various MIME types to never ask to download
- Loading the document in the browser, getting the source, and writing that out to a file (the browser won't render it as it's got the wrong MIME type)

My current chrome options look like this:

```
HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", directoryName);
chromePrefs.put("helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", Arrays.asList("text/plain", "application/xls", "application/csv", "application/force-download", "application/octet-stream", "application/vnd.ms-excel"));
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk=text/plain");
options.addArguments("--browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk=application/csv");
options.addArguments("--browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk=application/xls");
options.addArguments("--browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk=application/force-download");
options.addArguments("--browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk=application/octet-stream");
options.addArguments("--browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk=application/vnd.ms-excel");

options.addArguments("--browser.download.dir="+directoryName);

options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches",  Arrays.asList("enable-automation", "disable-popup-blocking"));
options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);

options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
```

I'm butting my head up against a brick wall here and would really appreciate if anybody has any insight into how I can achieve this!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add this `options.addArguments("--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=1920,1080","--ignore-certificate-errors");`

Comment: @pburgr thanks, tried that but alas no change!

Comment: Any solution yet?If yes please update the answer